# Conflict between gb4e and standalone

Tags: lists, incompatibility, standalone, linguistics, gb4e

Using an `\exe` environment in a document with the class ‘standalone’ is problematic for me. Here’s a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex German:
    \gll Dies ist    ein            Test. \\
         This be.3SG INDEF.M.SG.NOM test. \\
    \glt “This is a test.”
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

What happens is that I always get errors of the following kind:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8     \ex G
             erman:
```

Using `\documentclass{article}`, this code compiles without problems. It seems that `standalone` has a problem with the way `gb4e` uses lists to handle the individual rows in interlinear glosses?

The output should be a PDF/PNG file that looks like this:

[image: Correctly formatted interlinear gloss]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `preview` or `varwidth` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex German:
    \gll Dies ist    ein            Test. \\
         This be.3SG INDEF.M.SG.NOM test. \\
    \glt “This is a test.”
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can someone explain why this works?